# MSDTC component generated an exception in Windows 2012 server

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-server-2012, msdtc

My Dotnet 4.0 application recieving messages from IBM MQ and putting into database. It is using Distributed transactions. In windows 2012 server sometimes MSDTC is throwing below error.

An MS DTC component has generated an exception. Error Specifics: The process '"D:\test\sampleApp.exe" "D:\test\sampleApp.exe.config"' hit an exception in a MSDTC related component.
The following exception (0xc0000005) was generated at 0x        4DFA7E9F, Pid:8788.
The process is being terminated.
Additional information useful in a debugger:
You can do '.exr 0x0585E680' to display the exception record.
You can do '.cxr 0x0585E6D0' to display the context at the time of the exception.

0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. we installed IBM MQ v7.0 version and this version of MQ is not certified with windows 2012 server.